# How to know that a parameter is an array?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm working with reflection and when I get the parameters' list of a method, I need to examine all of them, when I find any one which its type is an **array** I need to avoid it, I mean array **of any kind**, so I used the following which doesn't work:

```
(!(parameter.GetType().Equals(Array)))
```

The error was that I'm using a type as a variable!! What can I do to accomplish that, any suggestions??

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
(!(parameter.GetType().IsArray))
```

NOTE - from MSDN:

> The IsArray property returns false for
>   the Array class.
>
> To check for an array, use code such
>   as
>   typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(type).
>
> If the current Type represents a
>   generic type, or a type parameter in
>   the definition of a generic type or
>   generic method, this property always
>   returns false.

Meaning that if you have simple array declarations like int[], string[], etc etc, the `IsArray` is fine, but if not then you will have to use `IsAssignableFrom()`.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* using a type ('Array') as a variable.  There is a difference between a variable of type 'System.Type' (represents a type) and an actual type. To convert a type to a System.Type you use typeof(type).

Now, you don't want all things that are type Array, but rather those objects that could be assigned to an object that is type Array (i.e. Array or its descendants).  It's a little backwards but the way to do that is to see if the System.Type for Array is assignable from the System.Type for your variable's type.

So, as a general pattern you want to try something like this:

```
( !(typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.GetType())) )
```

However, as another answer shows, System.Type has an IsArray property which skips this for you, so long as you are dealing with an actual array (int[], bool[] etc.) and not a custom Array descendant (e.g. something like CustomArrayClass : Array).

Comment: Both answers you wrote, didn't work they returned false!! I tired many types but it returns nothing but false !!

Comment: It should return false? It has a ("!") which is what you want (if NOT an array?)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using parameters, I shouldn't use "GetType", like this:

```
( !(typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.GetType())) )
```

This only works for assigned objects, with parameters this will return the type **parameterInfo**.

For parameters, "ParameterType" should be used and answer will look like this:

```
( !(typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.ParameterType)))
```

Comment: You didn't mention that you were working with a parameterinfo. It was implied that parameter was the name of one of your parameters (e.g. an object passed in). Glad to see you worked it out anyway.